# restricting access to a file in git repo like submodule without another repo

Tags: git

I am having a git repository and i have some files in it, one of the files size is very large, so everyone cloning this repository takes too much time and bandwidth. git submodule is the one option i saw to isolate this file from default cloning but it requires another repository, is there any other way without creating another repository.

Comment: Keeping it in a separate branch? Then you could check it out using a worktree.... but that would still make cloning long.

Comment: 'no' is probably the answer the the asked question. What is this large file and how big is it? Does it change (Does it need version control)?

Comment: `git-lfs` was made to store the content of large files outside the repo itself ; it could be a part of a solution to your issue.